# React native : error on Ios but not on android

Tags: react-native, expo

My app works fine on Android but when I launch it on Ios I get this error :

> **range error: maximum call stack size exceeded react-native**

[image]

I get that there should be an infinite loop somewhere in the code? But why not on android ?
in the metro bundler I have :

**> Unable to start your application. Please refer to https://expo.fyi/no-registered-application for more information.**

The app.json hasn't change lately...

I truly don't know where to look, there is a lot of files. Again, everything is ok on Android... I'm lost  , maybe someone can give me a lead on where to look for that kind of error.
I don't know which files cause the error...
Here's my App.js but I don't know if the problem is here :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isFirstConnection: true,
      status: 0,
      fontLoaded: false
    };
  }

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
    let isConnected = await userSessionActive();

    if (lang.length == 2) {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    }

    if (isConnected === true && this.props && this.props.navigation) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("TabBar");
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      FunctionLH: require("./assets/fonts/FunctionLH-Light.ttf"),
    });

    const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();
    if (data !== null) {
      this.setState({
        isFirstConnection: false,
        status: 1,
        fontLoaded: true,
      });
    }
  }

  performTimeConsumingTask = async () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("result");
      }, 1500)
    );
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.status == 1) {
      if (this.state.isFirstConnection && this.state.fontLoaded) {
        return <SplashScreen />;
      } else {
        return <Navigation screenProps= {'Authentication'} />;
      }
    }

    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("./assets/images/background.jpg")}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        <View style={[styles2.container, styles2.containerCentered]}>
          <StatusBar hidden={true} />
          <View style={styles2.subContainer}>
            <Image
              style={styles2.logo}
              source={require("./assets/images/logo.png")}
            />
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#43300E" />
            <Text>{i18n.t("app.loading") + "..."}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would be better if you post the code.

Comment: I know but I have a lot of files and I just don't know which one makes the error.. I 've edited with App.js but I'm not sure the problem is here

Comment: hi,in this situation what i do is remove all external elements and components from app.js mand then add them 1 by 1 to find the exact caus of error,also you can share git repo if its possible so i can try on it

Comment: thanks a lot I'm gonna try it

Comment: The problem seemed to be due to a database file too big. Splitting it in 2 has resolved the problem.  I still find very weird that the error was only in Ios but... 
Thanks a lot for helping me !